# how to get the timezone name which are currently set in my Codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter, timezone

I am dynamically setting the timezone in my Codeigniter web project by using: `date_default_timezone_set($this->session->userdata('timezone'));`

For debugging purposes, I want to check whether the timezone name which I have set using: `date_default_timezone_set($this->session->userdata('timezone'));`

How can I check which timezone is set in my web project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following function?

```
date_default_timezone_get();
```

Comment: Yes thanks , its working i kept `print(date_default_timezone_get());`